# How do portable servers work?

Tags: invisible-inc

The description for a Portable Server I gadget is the following:

> Portable Server I
>
> A portable server slowly increases the agents' connection to
>   Incognita. Security forces will disrupt it if it is found.
>
> Generates 1 PWR per 2 turns when deployed. Deploying has a 2 turn
>   cooldown.
>
> COOLDOWN 2 turn cooldown

1. Since the gadget description says that it has a 2 turn cooldown, does that mean I can deploy a server multiple times per level?
2. Or does it mean I can only deploy it once per level, and if I pick it up again, I have to wait another 2 turns before I can deploy it again?
3. Is it even possible to pick up a deployed server again, like with the camera canister gadget?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Portable Server is a deployable item similar to a camera cannister. You can place it down anywhere and it immediately starts generating power for you every turn. You can pick it up at any time by walking over it and clicking **Pickup Items**. The two turn cooldown begins when you pick it up. It's a very powerful and useful item, which is why it is so expensive. Place it in an out of the way place, as if a guard spots it, they will become alarmed. They will also take it. If you forget to pick it up before you leave the level, a reminder message will, fortunately, pop up when you try to activate the teleporter.

Comment: I've never used either of these types of items, what happens if you leave the level without picking the object back up? Is the item them lost?

Comment: Yes, the item is gone. I accidentally did that with the first camera canister I found. What I've been doing with the server is, as soon as I find the exit, moving the server to right next to it so it's easy to grab on the way out.

Comment: Good to know and that sounds like a sensible tactic. What happens if a guard finds it?

Comment: That I don't know. I did the testing for this answer on a level I had pretty much under control, and I didn't think to let a guard stumble over it. I'll find out sometime today and let you know

Comment: Ahaha. If a guard spots it, they go "Found something they left behind!" and run over and grab it. Wups.